# Replace commas and dashes in a pandas data frame with blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

When I use the `replace` function in df, it turns all values blank.

df:

```
SR_NO  NTN          NAME    
1      0000020-4    wang's hong & liang 
2      0000092-2    the bank of khyber ltd  
3      0000094-9    al khair gadoon limited 
4      0000098-1    ace weavers pvt. ltd,
5      0000131-7    niaz private limited
```

Code:

```
dictionary = {'-':'', 'pvt':'private', 'ltd':'limited', '.': '', '&': ' and ', ''':''} 

df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
SR_NO  NTN          NAME    
1       
2
3
4
5
```

The desired result would be:

```
SR_NO  NTN          NAME    
1      00000204     wangs hong and liang    
2      00000922     the bank of khyber limited
3      00000949     al khair gadoon limited 
4      00000981     ace weavers private limited
5      00001317     niaz private limited
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you user `regex=True` the regex `.` is everything an therefore it would result in an empty string. To replace only the points, use -

```
dictionary = {'-':'', 'pvt':'private', 'ltd':'limited', '\.': '', '&': ' and ', '\'':''}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need escape `.`, because special regex character for select all strings values:

```
dictionary = {'-':'', 'pvt':'private', 'ltd':'limited', '\.': '', '&': ' and ', "'":''} 

df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)

print (df)
   SR_NO       NTN                          NAME
0      1  00000204        wangs hong  and  liang
1      2  00000922    the bank of khyber limited
2      3  00000949       al khair gadoon limited
3      4  00000981  ace weavers private limited,
4      5  00001317          niaz private limited
```